# Can anyone solve this issue? I cannot connect to local host "Xamarin" "C"

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin, localhost

I followed one tutorial on how to connect to Mysql database. It connected to db4free.net , But its refusing to connect to localhost.
Needed Help... [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xZ7c.png)

Comment: MySQL db doesn't exist in the android emulator you should specify IP address of the host machine and direct connection between a mobile or desktop application to DB server is a very bad idea and security risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is, that you try to connect to the localhost on your phone. And there won't be any instance of MySql. A better and more recommended way is to abstract the database behind a webservice. Than you can easily communicate with that service inside your app.

Please read the [Xamarin guide about webservices](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/) for further information on that topic.